# How to display an already loaded loader icon on pop-up divs for multiple click events

Tags: jquery, popup

I am using JQuery 1.8.1 in my web-application. I am trying to `display a loader icon` on my pop-ups which stays on the div until the ajax-request is completed.

The image to be displayed is `already loaded and present (hidden) on the main page`.

```
<img id="myLoader" alt="" src="images/throbber.gif" style="display: none;"/>
```

On clicking the link that displays the pop-up, I place the loader icon on pop-up div. The div is overwritten with data received when ajax request completes.

```
$('a#popup').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        displayPop();
        $('div#popupdiv').html($('img#myLoader').show());
        $.ajax({
            url: 'someURL',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json'
        }).success(function(data){
             $('div#popupdiv').html(data);
        });
});
```

It works only once. And for all other `$('a#popup')` calls its blank. 
On debugging from firebug, I saw that `$('img#myLoader')` returns `Object[img#myLoader images/throbber.gif]` on the first call but `Object[]` is returned for the rest. As a novice in client-side coding, I am not able to grasp what's happening.

How can I display a loader icon on the pop-up div before the ajax request completes? I don't want to use any ajax requests for the loader itself. Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. The problem is in applying jQuery function `html` to jQuery object: `$('div#popupdiv').html($('img#myLoader'))`. After this operation object behaved very strangely. Documentation is clarified that you can use `html` method only with `htmlString`. I think you can solve you poblem by using `append` instead `html` (this one  can work with `jQuery`). I can suggest something like this:

`var imgLoader = $('img#myLoader').show().remove();`

```
$('a#popup').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    displayPop();
    $('div#popupdiv').append(imgLoader.clone());
    $.ajax({
        url: 'someURL',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json'
    }).success(function(data){
         $('div#popupdiv').html(data);
    });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

there are two events you can handle which does task of yours

```
beforeSend: function () {
        loading();
    },
```

on loading you display your image of loading

```
complete: function () {
     //here you disable that loading image.
    }
```

for more events refer : api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

Comment: thanks for the response. the actual problem is $('img#myLoader') becomes empty when the ajax request completes. So using a before send doesn't solve the issue. It is behaving similar to my code above

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using classes instead of IDs for the links?

Also, I would move the:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

to the very end of the function.